# Type of instance of self

Tags: typescript

```
class ThingOne {
  one: '1'
  public constructor(choice: keyof me) {
    console.log(this[choice])
  }
}
class ThingTwo extends Thing {
  two: '2'
}
new ThingOne('one') // 1
new ThingOne('two') // TypeError
new ThingTwo('two') // 2
```

Is there anything that can be used in place of 'me' in this example? (minus using generics to do it explicitly)

Answer (score 2):

For non-static instance members you can use the `this` polymorphic type:

```
class ThingOne {
    one: '1'
    public do(choice: keyof this) {
        console.log(this[choice as keyof this])
    }
}
class ThingTwo extends ThingOne {
    two: '2'
}
new ThingOne().do('one') // 1
new ThingOne().do('two') // TypeError
new ThingTwo().do('two') // 2
```

Unfortunately `this` is not usable in a constructor parameter. You can work around this in several ways, one way would be to add a generic parameter to the class that will be the type that the keys are taken from and use a bit of conditional type magic to make it work well:

```
class ThingOne<T extends ThingOne = never> {
    one: '1'
    public constructor(choice: T extends never ? keyof ThingOne: keyof T)
    public constructor(choice: keyof ThingOne) {
        console.log(this[choice as keyof this])
    }
}
class ThingTwo<T extends ThingTwo = never> extends ThingOne< T extends never ? ThingTwo: T> {
    two: '2'
}
new ThingOne('one') // 1
new ThingOne('two') // TypeError
new ThingTwo('two') // 2
```

There is a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) on this topic, it might be implemented at a later date, check the ticket before following the above workaround.

Comment: Haha that's a bummer. That was just the thing I was trying to avoid. Thanks for the issue link, do you get the impression it might ever be added?

Comment: @MoreThanTom I'm not the right person to ask that. I didn't see any technical issues in the thread, Ryan Cavanaugh mentions it's in their huge backlog of suggestions, it's probably a low priority item. I tried to make the generics as painless to use as possible...